# Signal getting multiple contents of several Qcomboxs as multiple parameters in function

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, signals-slots, qcombobox

I have 3 `QCombobox` with different contents wants to get currentindexs of all 3 `Qcombobox` and send them just to one function as multiple parameters. I do not know that could be possible in `PyQt5`?

```
    # Creating multiple comboxs
    self.combo_1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    self.combo_1.addItems(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
    self.combo_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    self.combo_2.addItems([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    self.combo_3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    self.combo_3.addItems(['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V'])

    ----------------------------------
    # Creating singal and slots
    self.combo_1.activated[int].connect(self.getindex)
    self.combo_2.activated[int].connect(self.getindex)
    self.combo_3.activated[int].connect(self.getindex)
    self.combo_1.activated.emit(self.combo_1.currentIndex())
    self.combo_2.activated.emit(self.combo_2.currentIndex())
    self.combo_3.activated.emit(self.combo_3.currentIndex())

    ----------------------------------
    # forward it to function
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def getindex(self, index1, index2, index3 ):
        print('{} index from combo_1'.format(index1))
        print('{} index from combo_2'.format(index2))
        print('{} index from combo_3'.format(index3))
```

How could I achieve this behavour? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QComboBox are a member of the class so you can get the indexes using the currentIndex() method:

```
    self.combo_1.activated.connect(self.getindex)
    self.combo_2.activated.connect(self.getindex)
    self.combo_3.activated.connect(self.getindex)
    self.getIndex()

@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def getindex(self):
    index1 = self.combo_1.currentIndex()
    index2 = self.combo_2.currentIndex()
    index3 = self.combo_2.currentIndex()
    print('{} index from combo_1'.format(index1))
    print('{} index from combo_2'.format(index2))
    print('{} index from combo_3'.format(index3))
```

Comment: The provided solution works fine, but does it work at startup, because self.combo_1.activated..emit() results in int error?

Comment: @Pavel.D 1) I do not get an error in that line but if I get the error in `self.combo_2.addItems([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` since QComboBox does not accept list of numbers but strings, it changes to `self.combo_2.addItems(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"])` 2) Have you passed any number to emit()? In the code of your question if you pass but in your comment no

Comment: No I do not pass any number to emit(). I solve this startup issue by making en custom signal and slot: `startup = QtCore.pyqtSignal()`, and add 2 extra line:         `self.startup.connect(self.getindex)`, `self.startup.emit()`. and it forces running the function at startup, in this way does not need any conversion from integer to string.

Comment: @Pavel.D That is the error, in the case of activated you need an integer, but if you want the getindex function to run at the beginning then call it directly. See my update. It is not necessary to create a new signal

Comment: You are indeed right, no need to custom signal and slot. Just call the function.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you would like to use `activated` instead of `currentIndexChanged`?
If you would like to activate only one function then solution of eyllanesc is great. But if you would like to use it outside Widget class I suggest to create custom signal and method which will calculate value for it.

Here is how I will solve it in generic way.

```py
from typing import List
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QComboBox, QHBoxLayout, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot


class ComboBoxGroup(QWidget):
    indexes_changed = pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self, initial_values: List[List[str]]):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.combos = []
        for values in initial_values:
            combo_box = QComboBox()
            combo_box.addItems(values)
            combo_box.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.value_changed)
            layout.addWidget(combo_box)
            self.combos.append(combo_box)
        self.setLayout(layout)


    def value_changed(self):
        res = [x.currentIndex() for x in self.combos]
        self.indexes_changed.emit(res)


def test(values: List[int]):
    print("current indexes: " + ",".join(map(str, values)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    group = ComboBoxGroup([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V']])
    group.indexes_changed.connect(test)
    group.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Great and fantastic! Your alternative solution is very interessant. No doubt this could be use! Thanks for that.